# Object Extension Methods on Value Types

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance, extension-methods, value-type

I have an Extension Method:

```
public static string ToDelimenatedString(this object[] array, string delaminator) {...}
```

The Extension is applied to reference types but not value types. I assume this is because object is nullable. How would I write the method above to target value types, is it even possible without writing it out for each value type?

Cheers,

Rich

Comment: are you delimenating, delaminating or delimiting your strings? :P

Comment: I couldn't seem to make my mind up. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work fine with generics:-

```
public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this T[] array, string delimiter)
```

FYI you could [but would likely not want to] do pretty much the inverse to constrain that not to work on value types by saying:

```
public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this T[] array, string delimiter)
    where T:class
```

BTW you'll probably also want to support IEnumerable, posiibly as an overload like this:-

```
public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string delimiter)
{
    return string.Join( delimiter, items.Select( item=>item.ToString()).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I must be having a bad morning, generics didn't even occur to me. Thanks for your help.